# C# current application Path and file name

Tags: c#

I want to open file with current application localization and file name.
I have done something like this: `private string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);`
and than I try to do `appPath + "filename"`, but I got an exeption with no file found. When I manually write localization of file it is found and it can be open. Could you help me?

Comment: When you get the `FileNotFoundException`, have you tried looking at the [FileName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if the path is constructed correctly?

Comment: Debugging the value of `appPath + "filename"` would have made it very obvious what the problem was.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:  `Path.Combine(appPath, "filename");`.

Most likely it's a missing backslash (or whatever the path separator char is on your system) between the `appPath` and the file name.  The `Combine` method will take care of that for you.